# What's wrong with my SOAP call to OnTime from my SVN post-commit hook?

Tags: perl, svn, post-commit, ontime

My Subversion repository is on a Linux server and my OnTime 2007 system is on a Windows 2003 server. I have a post-commit hook script that launches two Perl scripts.  One sends an email—works great. The other is supposed to write the details from the SVN commit to the Notes section of the OnTime tracking system.

I have lots of debugging statements in the Perl scripts, so I can see that the details of the commit are accurately retrieved.  The problem is writing them to OnTime.  I'm using SOAP to pass the details, but it isn't working.  The code is:

```
$service = SOAP::Lite->uii(URI)
$service->proxy(URL_to_OnTime)
$service->on_action(sub{URI . UpdateDefectNotes})
$method = SOAP::Data->name(UpdateDefectNotes)->attr({xmlns=>URI})
$response = $service->call($method => $defectid,$name,$revisionid,$notes)
```

The response code I get back is `1`, but I don't know if this is success or failure.  All I know is that the Notes section in OnTime for the `defectid` is NOT updated.

Can anyone help?

Nancy

Comment: I suggest adding a code block around your code, so that it doesn't show up in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in to display the XML request/response.

```
$service->on_debug( sub { print @_ } );
```